# Detecting the available internet proxy servers in LAN

Tags: .net, windows, proxy, network-programming

I have to use an internet proxy server when I connect to a wifi network in a certain location, and then undo in when I connect it at home. I want to create a program to automate this.
How can I detect if there are any proxy servers in LAN offering internet, and whether internet is available at the moment through (by pinging or something) using C# or VB.NET; so that I can create a tool for this.
Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Do you want to write an application for this, or using already written applications is enough?

I had same problem years ago, with my laptop when I go to customers I needed to change network configuration to use their proxy servers, and at home again I was switching to normal.

There are many free applications that you can save different configurations.

http://www.netsetman.com/index.php?s=nsm

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. Already written application helps my situation a lot and thank you very much for the link. I want to know how to create similar application as well, because I like to develop something which can automatically detect available proxies, since in other applications we have to save each profiles in advance.